# Usefulness of identifier variables in ML model building

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, neural-networks, classification

I have a dataset with 1000 rows and I have an identifier variable called `person_id`.

May I check why is it told that we should remove identifier variables from ML model?

I ask because in my dataset, the same person can occur multiple times. Menaing, the same person has consulted the doctor multiple times. So, we have multiple observations of him.

So, my questions are as follows

a) Why should we remove identifier variables from ML model? If not, how useful are they?

b) If we remove identifier variable, how will I link the predicted outcome with the `person_id`?

Let's say my algo predicts that this specific instance is `positive` but if I remove the `person_id` column, how can I know that this prediction is for a specific person (with id = blabla) because we would have removed his Id.

c) Even if a identifier column is completely unique (like a serial number), should we still remove them from the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: Keep it for identification, but don't pass it into the ML model.

(c & a) We should. To me, we train a model to generalize all of your persons. So if you treat your `person_id` as a categorical feature, because no two persons share the same `person_id`, one `person_id` does not speak anything about another person, so it lacks the power to generalize. If you treat it like a continuous feature, then you may have a very hard time when justifying why you should order persons in the way it is, i.e. why person A should be followed by person B but not person C.

(b) Just don't give it to the ML model, keep it anywhere else :)

Comment: thanks for the response. upvoted. So, I should keep a copy/make a note somewhere that row 1/index 1 belongs to person_id = 1. Once the prediction is over, I come back and link the person_id column to prediction table (to identify that row 1 belongs to person_id = 1)...Is this how ML models are deployed in real time?

Comment: yes, your `model.predict` should not mess up the ordering, so you can remove and save the `person_id` before passing the data into the `predict`, and add it back to the result of the prediction.

Comment: thanks for your help. Appreciate your inputs